# Unity mesh collider raycast not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can not seem to get the raycast to hit the mesh collider. I need this to get the texture uv coordinates.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100f))
    {
        // We've hit this mesh b/c its the only one we have ...
        var texture = meshRenderer.material.mainTexture as Texture2D;

        var pixelUV = hit.textureCoord;
        print("pixs uvs" + pixelUV.ToString());
        pixelUV.x *= texture.width;
        pixelUV.y *= texture.height;

        var position = new Position(pixelUV.x, pixelUV.y);
        print("Position: " + position.x + " " + position.y);

        texture.FloodFillBorder(position.x, position.y, fillColor, borderColor);
        texture.Apply();
    }
}
```

My game object has this script with the update function checking for input, as well as mesh filter, mesh renderer, and mesh collider. The mesh is a simple quad made from unity's menu.

What am I doing wrong? I just do not understand why it is not hitting the mesh. The camera's `z position` is `-10` and the mesh is at `0`. Placing differently gives the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Mesh component and see if 'IsTrigger' is checked but may i suggest something else?

Unity does whole this ray casting for you by default. MonoBehaviour class has functions such as  OnMouseDown() or onMouseDrag() etc. where a GUIElement or in your case an object with Collider component gets these events. So if your game object has a collider component just implement one of these methods and you are ready to go.

This may you can keep your update function clean.

Check: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, I need the uv coordinates from the hit object. Nonetheless I just decided to go with a much easier way of simply determining where the person clicked by converting few coordinates.